# ios 7.1 enterprise distribution server's certificates error

Tags: ios, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, ad-hoc-distribution

Since I update to iOS 7.1 I had to start using a secure conexion to be able to download the plist file, I received the following:

```
    Mar 21 09:08:36 xx-iPad itunesstored[98] <Warning>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "Cannot connect to the Store" 
UserInfo=0x16ec5500 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to the Store, 
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=A secure connection could not be established.  Please check your Date & Time settings., 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mydomain/myappanme.plist, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x16dd7fa0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mydomain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", 
NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x16e04510>, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://anything/myappanme.plist}
```

My server it is configured like this:
We've got a wildcard certificate for `*.mydomain.com`. We moved it to a new server, and the certificate is valid for all browsers that we have tested. (IE, firefox, chrome, safari...). The certificate is the tipical CRT with a bundle/intermediate certificate from GoDaddy and the key. The https site loads without issues. Apache 2.4 and Linux Fedora 20.

The download to install the app is:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mydomain/resources/myappanme.plist
```

Posible duplicated questions (try them all)

-)[The certificate for this server is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197834/the-certificate-for-this-server-is-invalid)

-)[iOS Enterprise OTA distribution Unable to Download Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167915/ios-enterprise-ota-distribution-unable-to-download-application)
-)http://www.nefkens-ict.nl/enterprise-build-does-not-install/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below link, which will help you solving this certificate problem

http://cases.azoft.com/how-to-fix-certificate-is-not-valid-error-on-ios-7/

Answer (score 1):

No issue in sharing the .ipa or apk file, for quick round, you can use below link to share binary file's, using multiple recipients...

URL:
[thebetafamily.com/supersend/](http://thebetafamily.com/supersend/)

Comment: Looks nice, but in case it is normal apple distribution profile (not enterprise one), do you have to add the UUID device of the testers in the apple provisioning profile ?